# Not able to hide set area using C# Code

Tags: c#, sharepoint

We are not able to hide the SET area that is displayed in top navigation bar, I am using the below code snippet to achieve the same. But the subsite is not getting hidden even when the code is not throwing any error. Bit clueless as after unsafe update the code is functioning as expected.

Code Snippet:

```
using (SPSite siteCollection = new SPSite("http://****:****/VijaiTest/"))
{
    using (SPWeb web = siteCollection.RootWeb)
    {
        PublishingWeb publishingWeb = PublishingWeb.GetPublishingWeb(web);
        // Global Navigation 
        //Show Subsites 
        publishingWeb.Navigation.GlobalIncludeSubSites = false;
        //Show Pages 
        publishingWeb.Navigation.GlobalIncludePages = false;
        // Maximum number of dynamic items to show within this level of navigation: 
        publishingWeb.Navigation.GlobalDynamicChildLimit = 60;

        publishingWeb.IncludeInCurrentNavigation = false;

        web.AllowUnsafeUpdates = true;

        SPSecurity.RunWithElevatedPrivileges(delegate()
        {
            //Update the changes
            publishingWeb.Update();
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: What do you mean by "SET area"?

Answer (score 0):

I see a few potential problems with your code...

**1. Don't wrap `SPWeb web = sitecollection.RootWeb` in a `Using` statement**

While normally it's good practice to wrap SPSite and SPWeb objects in `Using` statements to ensure that they're disposed of properly, the `SPSite.RootWeb` property is an exception to this rule. The root web is disposed *automatically* along with the SPSite object, when it is disposed. Since you have `SPSite siteCollection = new SPSite(...` wrapped in a `Using` statement, you don't need to worry about disposal of the `RootWeb`.

Trying to dispose of the root web twice will add errors to your logs and can cause problems when accessing that web object programmatically.

**2. Instantiate your SPSite and SPWeb objects inside your `SPSecurity.RunWithElevatedPrivileges` delegate**

For `SPSecurity.RunWithElevatedPrivileges` to be effective, you must retrieve or create your SPSite and SPWeb objects within the delegate function.

Your code obtains the SPSite and SPWeb objects prior to running `RunWithElevatedPrivileges`, so any operations on those objects will run under the context of the current user instead of running with elevated privileges.

**3. Check to be sure the SPWeb object is a valid PublishingWeb before executing `GetPublishingWeb(web)`**

From [Microsoft](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ms497306(v=office.14).aspx):

> Before you use this method, check the [IsPublishingWeb](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/microsoft.sharepoint.publishing.publishingweb.ispublishingweb(v=office.14).aspx) method to confirm that publishing behavior is supported on this instance of the [SPWeb](http://msdn2.microsoft.com/EN-US/library/ms473942) class. If publishing is not supported on the [SPWeb](http://msdn2.microsoft.com/EN-US/library/ms473942), then the methods and properties of the [PublishingWeb](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/microsoft.sharepoint.publishing.publishingweb(v=office.14).aspx) wrapper may behave unexpectedly.

After those changes, your code would look like this:

```cs
SPSecurity.RunWithElevatedPrivileges(delegate() {
    using(SPSite siteCollection = new SPSite("http://****:****/VijaiTest/")) {
        SPWeb web = siteCollection.RootWeb;
        if(PublishingWeb.IsPublishingWeb(web)){
            PublishingWeb publishingWeb = PublishingWeb.GetPublishingWeb(web);
            // Don't show Subsites 
            publishingWeb.Navigation.GlobalIncludeSubSites = false;
            // Don't show Pages 
            publishingWeb.Navigation.GlobalIncludePages = false;
            // Maximum number of dynamic items to show within this level of navigation: 
            publishingWeb.Navigation.GlobalDynamicChildLimit = 60;
            publishingWeb.IncludeInCurrentNavigation = false;
            web.AllowUnsafeUpdates = true;
            //Update the changes
            publishingWeb.Update();
        }else{
            throw new Exception("Web is not a publishing web");
        }
    }
});
```